# What is the easiest way to migrate posgresql database to another server?

Tags: postgresql, migration

I have set up my **PostgreSQL** database on the server up and running, but soon the server is going to be destroyed, so I need to migrate the database to another server? What is the most comprehensive approach to that, with a note that the database has data in its tables?

Comment: Is it only a single database you need to migrate or there's multiple databases?

Comment: Just a single database instance

Comment: If you want _everything_ that's part of the current Postgres cluster (including users and passwords) and the new server uses the same operating system (and operating system version), you can use `pg_basebackup` to copy the entire data directory to the new server. If  it's really only one (of several) databases on the old server, use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` to transfer a single database.

Comment: After copying the entire data directory to the new server, be sure to set the necessary file permissions on the folder, and edit the config files to set the new server IP address.

Answer (score 2):

If the architecture on both systems is the same, (say, 64-bit Linux on the same hardware architecture), you can simply copy the data directory. There are a few things to observe:

- you have to use the same PostgreSQL versions on both systems
- unless the C library version is the same or you are using the `C` collation, you had better reindex all indexes on string expressions, because the collation might have changed